# SILENT POSTBACK 2 DIFFERENT SERVERS

Tags: postback, silent

I have two different servers, but one paypal account (second server is not live yet). Is it possible to set up more than one configuration in order to direct the SILENT POST BACK and the FAILED SILENT POST URL to each of these servers? Or do we need an additional license because it is 2 separate sites? Thank you for your help.